# The sdk platform-tools version (26.0.2) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 27; please update

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, sdk, platform-tools

I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 2017.2.5 and am building an Android app.

My problem is that even if in my app (Gradle) I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.mtvtr"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Also, on first build of the project, compile for the appcompat, design and support was set to 27+ (which IMHO is bad practice and is already pointed by the Studio as a bad idea), so using which tools that I have, I have set it to 27.0.1, and later to 27.0.0 just for the testing if it might work..

In my Fragments and Activities I have:

[image: Package-code]

And the warning says:

> The sdk platform-tools version (26.0.2) is too old to check APIs
>   compiled with API 27; please update

Now, I know that there are topics on SO regarding old and new versions, but I have (to my belief) set the Gradle properly and I am nowhere using platform-tools version 26 or even 26.0.2...

I have tried Restarting and invalidating caches three times.

The project properly builds onto the device and everything works. But, of course, I want to fix the warning. (And not hide it like some would suggest..)

Two things that come to mind are:

1. I missed somewhere that I should have updated the version, maybe?
2. I need to start a new project from scratch.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: See if it works with AS 3.0. It's not merged into IntelliJ IDEA yet.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, you might be onto something, I will try that, I have already downloaded newest AS, so I will go from there.. I always thought that firstly updates go into Idea and afterwards in AS :D

Comment: I have same issue And i cant upgrade Android studio to 3.0 due to live project  any solution ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It seems that it was an IDE problem because it worked without warnings inside Android Studio 3.0 as it was suggested by CrazyCoder.

It seems that at this moment IntelliJ Idea isn't updated enough to make this work properly. So even while I have been using Idea from the start, I will switch to AS for now. :)

Thanks for your input guys. :)

Comment: Check my recent posted answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this answer is the same as all of the above or below. At that moment this was the only course of action available. In the meantime, the updates came along with stuff to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 3.0 will be merged into IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 version, which will make the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` plugin compatible with it. That will make this error to go away.

For those of you who are experiencing this issue in Android Studio, check your root `build.gradle` file and make sure it is updated to the above mentioned plugin version (`3.0.0`), in order to be able to compile against API 27 with the current latest build tools (`26.0.2`).

You may consequently also have to update the Gradle wrapper to the latest (`4.1` at the time of this answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have just to launch the SDK Manager and download the *Android SDK Platform Tools* and *SDK Tools*.

Here the [official doc.](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager)

Comment: looking at the page https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html it looks like there is **no** SDK Platform-Tools 27. The latest is currently 26.0.2

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere It appears it's like that on that page, but inside the SDK Manager there is version 27 (even revision 27.0.1) and Gradle clearly suggests that there is a newer version. That may be the issue itself...?

Comment: The doc is not updated. The version 27 exists. Since you are using compileSdk 27 and support libraries v27 you should use also the version 27 of the platform tools.

Comment: this is what I've got https://imgur.com/a/lcX02 I believe it should show `Android SDK Platform-Tools 27` however it only shows 26.0.2  (Android Studio on Windows)

Comment: Happens to me also. 26.0.2 is the latest SDK Platform tools